# How can I compute the result of some integer modulo 10^100?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell. I have a code as:

```
mwave :: Int -> Int
mwave = (map wave [0..] !!)
  where wave 0 = 1
        wave 1 = 1
        wave n = ((3 * n - 3) * mwave (n - 2) + (2 * n + 1) * mwave (n - 1)) `div` (n + 2)

digits :: Int -> Int
digits n = (mwave n) `mod` 10^100::Integer
```

> ```
> Output:
> wave.exe: divide by zero
> ```

I have to output the answer modulo 10^100. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `Integer` not `Int`

Comment: @Bergi When I change the signature of `mwave`, it gives and error: `Couldn't match expected type `Integer' with actual type `Int'`

Comment: You'd need to change `digits` as well

Comment: @Bergi `mwave :: Int -> Integer` `digits :: Integer -> Int` does not work

Comment: It's `digits :: Int -> Integer` - the return value has the large values, not the parameter

Comment: @Bengi. Thanks but it says: `Couldn't match expected type 'Integer' with actual type 'Int'`

Comment: Where? Please cite the whole error message

Comment: Couldn't match expected type 'Integer' with actual type 'Int'
      In the expression: n 'mod' 10 ^ (100 :: Integer)
          In an equation for 'digits':
              digits n = n 'mod' 10 ^ (100 :: Integer)

Comment: Well that's not the function you posted in your question, no wonder that the type I'm recommending doesn't match. Is `digits` supposed to call `mwave` or not?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I changed the function to test a different case. The actual error is: `Couldn't match expected type 'Integer' with actual type 'Int'
    * In the expression: (mwave n) 'mod' 10 ^ (100 :: Integer)
      In an equation for 'digits':
          digits n = (mwave n) 'mod' 10 ^ (100 :: Integer)`

Comment: And `mwave` takes an `Int` and returns an `Integer` as well? I had assumed that was already established.

Comment: No, `mwave` takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`

Comment: You had commented you made it `mwave :: Int -> Integer`… It needs to return a large value of course, otherwise it's pointless to try to fit a `10^100` in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123887/discussion-between-zubin-kadva-and-bergi).